# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/win32/StdCallLibrary after exporting to jar file

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jna

I'm trying to write a java application to change my desktop wallpaper using cmd.

The code I have written so far:

```
package me.kaes3kuch3n.main;

import java.util.HashMap;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.UINT_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;

public class WallpaperUpdater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java -jar WallpaperUpdater.jar <path_to_wallpaper>");
        } else {
            String path = args[0];

            SPI.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(
                    new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER), 
                    new UINT_PTR(0), 
                    path, 
                    new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPI.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE));
        }

    }

    public interface SPI extends StdCallLibrary {

        //from MSDN article
        long SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
        long SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        long SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

        SPI INSTANCE = (SPI) Native.loadLibrary("user32", SPI.class, new HashMap<Object, Object>() {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            {
                put(OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
                put(OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
            }
        });

        boolean SystemParametersInfo(
                UINT_PTR uiAction,
                UINT_PTR uiParam,
                String pvParam,
                UINT_PTR fWinIni
                );
    }
}
```

It works just fine when I'm running it using Eclipse but after exporting it to a jar file it throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/win32/StdCallLibrary
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at me.kaes3kuch3n.main.WallpaperUpdater.main(WallpaperUpdater.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

I've added both the jna.jar and the jna-platform.jar to the build path, but it won't work. What am I missing?

Comment: provide your library project structure please.

Comment: Project is not identifying your jar.

Comment: Build path is one thing, exporting is another. You need to include those JAR files in runtime classpath.

Comment: @YeWin structure of my whole project: https://i.imgur.com/Vnhlrpe.png

Comment: @KCWong the JAR files are included in the runtime classpath (Eclipse: Run -> Run Configurations -> Classpath)

Comment: @Kaes3kuch3n If you have added the right JARs to the Run Configuration Classpath, then it should work... If you have multiple run configurations, make sure you are launching the correct one? Also, can you launch your application from commandline?

Comment: @Kaes3kuch3n , your project structure is look correct, can you expand the jna jars file from Reference Libraries and can find the your imported package??

Comment: @KCWong I guess I solved the problem. I was exporting it as a jar file instead of exporting it as a runnable jar file. Launching the application from command line also works fine. But while it changes the wallpaper now, it won't change it into the given image but instead paint it just black

Comment: @YeWin It's working now (just exported it as runnable jar file instead of jar file), but it won't display the given wallpaper but paint the background black instead